# How to make correctly downloading in browser from local network?

Tags: windows, security, web, browser

I want to make a link, that will download file from my local network. But when i press, i get a message: Not allowed to load local resource

```
<a href="file://192.168.30.51/MyProgram.exe" target="_blank" class="k-button">My app</a>
```

and

```
function downloadOfflineInstallerFromLocal() {
         window.open("file://192.168.30.51/MyProgram.exe",'_blank');
}
```

doesn't work.

How to fix it, not using --allow-file-access-from-files flag?

Comment: Some older versions of ie allowed you to do this but it is a security risk so it has been removed

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to files outside your server or "**SandBox**", sandbox includes the files that user push to the browser or to your server.

If the access from browser to a pc files from web pages was possible, it would be a security problem.

**In Simple words, You can't link to file:/// from an HTML document that is not itself a file:/// for security reasons.**